# Killing a dragon with a single Dragonrend shout?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My character is level 19 and I came across a dragon and went about to kill it the usual way (Dragonrend, Sword hacking).

Only this time, the dragon just died when I used Dragonrend. Is this possible? Are there weak dragons to look out for in Skyrim for some quick dragon souls?

EDIT: This is after I have:

> already killed Alduin and Paarthurnax.

Comment: I don't know if dragons can take fall damage, but if they can I'd guess that's what killed it after you dragonrend-ed it.

Comment: I'm on the Xbox so it's the latest version I guess.... All I know that happened is that I heard a dragon land behind me, I shouted Dragonrend and ran towards it and started hacking. That's when I realized that the Dragonrend killed it.

Comment: Well not necessarily; What I meant was that I finished the main story arc. You get Dragonrend way before you even enter Sovngarde.

Comment: @desaivv there are a lot of games (older and more recent) that I haven't played but would like to. I appreciate Sid hiding the spoilers and I'm sure others do too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dragonrend [apparently does an unspecified amount of health damage over time to dragons](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragonrend). Are you sure the dragon was at full health when you shouted at it? They are surprisingly frail creatures, when matched against groups of bandits or a giant.

Comment: @desaivv a) there are ranged weapons and spells in the game b) dragons land when they are above 50% health.

Comment: Well this was a dragon that landed behind me so maybe it was already at half health. I turned around, used Dragonrend, and it died. It happened too fast for me to check it's health.

Comment: Selecting this as the right answer because it was either a glitch or maybe the dragon was already damaged. Further bolstered by the fact that two dragons showed up at once which is a rare occurrence so maybe the game was glitching.

Answer (score -1):

well sometime the dragon has low life because the dragons wil get in fights with each other, because it says that when dragons use the frost breath or fire breath, they are having a strong verbal communication. so the dragon was probobly in a fight before it landed then when u used the dragon rend it finished it off, also some dragons are weaker than other, like the dragons that just say Dragon, they are weaker than the ones with names.

Comment: This answer does not add anything that the accepted answer already state. Also, this is a Q&A site, not a forum. Please read [answer] and do the [tour in our help section](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how this site works. This answer might end up being deleted.